# Ruby libxml: format XMLParser to expand closing tags

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, format, libxml2

I'm using libxml-ruby to parse XMLs in my application

I have the following code:

```
parser = LibXML::XML::Parser.string('<foo><bar></bar></foo>')
parser.parse
```

returning:

```
<foo><bar/></foo>
```

How do I set the XMLParser options, so it outputs:

```
<foo><bar></bar></foo>
```

Kind Regards

Comment: What do you mean by the parser is "returning"  `<foo><bar/></foo>`?  That is a serialized form, and the parser returns a DOM tree.  Your question has to do with serialization of a tree, not parsing of input XML text.